# Is a Native Quarkus Application better than one on the JVM?

Tags: quarkus

I am comparing the same Quarkus application in different executables, regular jar, fast-jar and native executable. To be able to compare them, I run the same performance test.

The results are the following:

- Regular Jar, starts in `0.904s`. Regarding performance, the result is given below:

  ```
  Running 1m test @ http://localhost:8080/hello
  2 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   361.86us    4.48ms 155.85ms   99.73%
    Req/Sec    29.86k     4.72k   37.60k    87.83%
  3565393 requests in 1.00m, 282.22MB read
  Requests/sec:  59324.15
  Transfer/sec:      4.70MB
  ```
- Fast-Jar, starts in `0.590s`. Regarding performance, the result is given below:

  ```
  Running 1m test @ http://localhost:8080/hello
  2 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   344.38us    3.89ms 142.71ms   99.74%
    Req/Sec    27.21k     6.52k   40.67k    73.48%
  3246932 requests in 1.00m, 257.01MB read
  Requests/sec:  54025.50
  Transfer/sec:      4.28MB
  ```
- Native, start in `0.011s`. Regarding performance, the result is given below:

  ```
  Running 1m test @ http://localhost:8080/hello
  2 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   303.72us  471.86us  29.00ms   98.05%
    Req/Sec    19.03k     3.21k   30.19k    78.75%
  2272236 requests in 1.00m, 179.86MB read
  Requests/sec:  37867.20
  Transfer/sec:      3.00MB
  ```

The number of requests processed in a native application is roughly 1 million less than a JVM Quarkus application. However, the starting up time, Avg and Stdev in native application is better than others.

I was wondering why this happens and if a native application is better than one over the JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start up time and memory consumption will definitely be better with native quarkus applications. This is because quarkus extends graalvm's native image concept.

From https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/

> native-image is a utility that processes all classes of an application
> and their dependencies, including those from the JDK. It statically
> analyzes these data to determine which classes and methods are
> reachable during the application execution. Then it ahead-of-time
> compiles that reachable code and data to a native executable for a
> specific operating system and architecture.

As the application is processed with ahead-of-time compilation and the JVM used (aka Substrate VM) contains only the essential part, the resulting program has faster startup time and lower runtime memory overhead compared to a JVM.